# Javascript split string every third space

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to split string on every third space. For example :

```
var str = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt';
//result will be:
var result = ["Lorem ipsum dolor ", "sit amet consectetur ", "adipiscing elit sed ", "do eiusmod tempor ", "incididunt"];
```

Please help me. Thank you

Comment: I already use that function, it's different. I want to split every third space not at certain position.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use regex for splitting the string.

```js
var str = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt';
var splited = str.match(/\b[\w']+(?:[^\w\n]+[\w']+){0,2}\b/g);
console.log(splited);
```

**Regex description:**

```
 1. \b assert position at a word boundary (^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)

 2. Match a single character present in the list below [\w']+
         \w matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_])

 3. {0,2} Quantifier — Matches between 0 and 2 times

 4. Match a single character not present in the list below [^\w\n]

 5. \w matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_])

 6. \n matches a line-feed (newline) character (ASCII 10)

 7. Match a single character present in the list below [\w']

 8. \w matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_])

 9. ' matches the character ' literally (case sensitive)

 10. \b assert position at a word boundary (^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)

 11. g modifier: global. All matches (don't return after first match)
```

Comment: kindly add the explanation for the regex :)

Comment: Wow what a regex.. Thank you for your answer and explanation :) I still need to learn how to use regex.

Comment: @brk Might want to add `<!-- language: lang-none -->` before the regex explanation codebox so that it doesn't colour it weirdly :)

Comment: @Spella It's easier than you think. Just go for it! [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2759417/2288578) is by far the best regex tutorial I found and it's how I learned.

Comment: Thank you very much.. I will follow this tutorial :)

Comment: I found that this regex pattern will emit the `(` and `)` characters in some cases, e.g. `This is an example (2020)` will emit the last `)`

Answer (score 4):

```js
var str = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt';
var splitString = str.match(/(.*?\s){3}/g);
console.log(splitString);
```

Comment: so simple.. thank you for giving solutions :)

Comment: Very nice, but should it really keep the trailing space at the end?

Answer (score 2):

check here https://regex101.com/r/npQt7X/1

or

```
const regex = /\b[\w']+(?:[^\w\n]+[\w']+){0,2}\b/g;
const str = `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }

    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Regexes are nice, but hard to explain and difficult to read.

So I use regexes only if there is no other solution.

An argument against these regexes is the hardcoding of the parameters.

```
var str = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt';

var splitMyString = (str, splitLength) => {
  var a = str.split(' '), b = [];
  while(a.length) b.push(a.splice(0,splitLength).join(' '));
  return b;
}
console.log(splitMyString(str,3));
```